# No Match on elpy

Tags: package, elpy

I am trying to install elpy.  I added the lines

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
     '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
      )

(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)

;; For elpy
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
;; For interactive shell
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
```

to my init.el file.  I ran `package-refresh-contents`.  It asked me permission to grant a connection, and I chose `Always`.  Then I try `package-install RET elpy RET`, but I get a no match.  I saw this:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30668/17291

But, my package-archive agrees with the only answer.  What should I try?  Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try `M-x list-packages`? elpy is not in the list?

Comment: @jerome It is on the list.

Comment: Try installing it from there? Typically you would put the point at the line where elpy is found, then type `i` to mark the package for install, and then `x` to execute. To see other commands available type `h`.